# What does "let go" mean in "lets her hearing aid go"?

Tags: verbs, phrasal-verbs

This context comes from the movie "Fight Club" (1999).

*"A foot of concrete is important when your next-door neighbor **lets her hearing aid go** and has to watch game shows at full volume. Or when a volcanic blast of debris that used to be your furniture and personal effects blows out of your floor-to-ceiling windows and sails flaming into the night. I suppose these things happen."*

I don't understand the bold part. Does "*let go*" here means:

b) to stop worrying or thinking too much about something
*It’s time to let the past go*. (Longman Dictionary)

Does it mean that she **stopped worrying about using the hearing aid?**

Comment: This looks like it could just be an error. It doesn't make much sense TBH.  Perhaps there is a missing word "go off"? Just a guess though. Are you relying on subtitles?  They can sometimes be wrong.

Comment: The subtitles on this clip  do not match what the actor is saying  but yours do https://clip.cafe/fight-club-1999/home-a-condo-on-the-15th-floor/

Answer (score 0):

In its definition for *let go*, Collins Dictionary [sense e](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/let-go) says

> e. to dismiss; forget; *discard*

> "A foot of concrete is important when your next-door neighbor *lets* her hearing aid *go* and has to watch game shows at full volume.

means the neighbour *discards* her hearing aid and will hence raise her TV volume.  Those unfortunate ones around this unit hence need a thick wall.

**Edit**

A common reason for a person to discontinue the use of his or her hearing aid is discomfort.

> Perhaps back in the late 80s and 90s hearing aids were more uncomfortable to wear, so in the comfort of their own home, those who were hard of hearing didn't to want to use it. (@Mari-Lou A)

Hence the neighbour simply stopped being bothered by her hearing needs and instead opted for confort--discarding the device.

Comment: However, to my ear, that sense of "let go" is only used of intangibles, like ideas, not of physical objects. I find the example in the question bizarre and uninterpretable. While it is obviously saying she does not use the hearing aid, I have no idea at all what it is saying about how or why she does not use it.

Comment: Thanks, @Colin Fine, for the comments.  [Page 81](https://books.google.com.sg/books?id=HSyY6ecS-GMC&pg=PA81&dq=%22let+the+money+go%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&source=gb_mobile_search&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj46-yoi42FAxVW7TgGHZfTBTAQ6wF6BAgOEAU#v=onepage&q=%22let%20the%20money%20go%22&f=false) first instance of *let the money go* has "... we are going to let the money go until it goes back to the owner ..."

Comment: @ColinFine Perhaps back in the late 80s and 90s hearing aids were more uncomfortable to wear, so in the comfort of their own home, those who were hard of hearing didn't to want to use it. A bit like a man coming back from work and immediately loosening their necktie.

Comment: Or lets the batteries in the hearing aid go "dead"?

Comment: @SeowjoohengSingapore: I wouldn't put too much faith in that dialogue you cite. First, Mr Jimenez previously says "We are putting back in the hands of the traffickers their profits", which I can't imagine any native English speaker saying. Secondly, it's not clear whether he is even using the complex verb "let go" - it might be read as "we will let the money go into" = "we will allow the money to go into".

Comment: @Mari-LouA I think you're the only person on this page that's understood the correct usage from OP's quote, and should write your own answer! "Let her hearing aid go," to me, unambiguously means the person allowed her hearing aid to *wear out/ become less functional* due to lack of maintenance. So, she's having to turn up the TV volume higher to compensate. "Let go" here is being used in the same sense as it is often used to refer to a yard https://www.google.com/search?q=%22let%20the%20yard%20go%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2014,cd_max:2019&lr=lang_en which the owner neglects to keep up

Comment: The link is to the page of Google Ngrams literature results (2014-2019), where there are many examples of the phrase being used in this context.